# How to customize this suggestion dropdown in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, styled-components, jetbrains-ide

[image]

I'm not sure since which version this started happen. I do remember when I type "aic", `align-items: center` was top choice. I don't remember others was there but below aic or wasn't even there. I need to know where those "P" suggests coming from and disable them. Because I usually write css, I use "df" for `display: flex`, "aic" for `align-items: center` etc. It was faster. But I no longer can.

Using WebStorm 2020.2.3 and plugin named Styled-components and Styled-jsx.

Comment: The suggestions on top of the list on the screenshot are standard CSS property and its vendor-specific options. There's no way to disable that in CSS files.
One of the options to have `ai:c` on top of the list would be to enable alphabetic sorting for completion suggestions in Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after long search, I found solution myself.
Go to Preference > Editor > Emmet > Css, then check "Enable fuzzy search among CSS abbrs". Now those abbrs I wanted are listed on top.